# p factorial minus p primorial

Tags: number-theory

Let be k# the primorial function. Let be $p$ a prime.

Is $19$ the only prime $p$ such that p!-p# is divisible by $p^2$? And why?

Answer (score 2):

Because of Wilson's theorem the given condition is equivalent to $\ p$# $\equiv -p\mod p^2\ $

Upto $10^6$ , the following primes do the job ($\ p=2\ $ and $\ p=3\ $lead to $\ 0\ $, so might better be ruled out) :

```
? s=1;forprime(p=1,10^6,s=s*p;if(Mod(s,p^2)==-p,print1(p," ")))
2 3 19 1471 3001
?
```

Comment: Maybe, OEIS knows this sequence ...

Comment: No further solution upto $10^7$

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. This is the one of many questions you have asked about particular numerical coincidences you  observed about primes. Most of those have been closed. There are   infinitely many primes and infinitely many possible coincidences so if you keep looking you will stumble across many.